# Setting grid pageSize to a variable in Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Using Kendo UI grid to build a list. Trying to set the pageSize parameter of the kendo.data.DataSource object.

I can set the pageSize to a variable initially (e.g. varPageSize = 20). I can increment the varPageSize variable through a button click (e.g. varPageSize += 10). The pageSize of the grid, however, is not updating.

Variable assignment:

```
var varPageSize = 20;
```

Partial code for grid:

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
     pageSize: varPageSize,
     ...
});
```

Code for click event handler

```
$('#moreButton').on('click', function () {
      varPageSize += 10;

      //print to the console to monitor the value of the varPageSize variable
      console.log(varPageSize);
});
```

My question is how I should go about implementing a variable assignment to the pageSize parameter so that it can be updated in response to front end events.

My initial thought is that I am not updating the grid after updating the variable value. Kendo UI forum posts from Telerik says to use grid.refresh(); - But the grid object doesn't recognize .refresh(). I've also looked for other questions on this topic and I am having a hard time identifying which one to translate to my solution - each existing post is a variant that I am not using (e.g. .pageSize();)

Any insight or push in the right direction is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set `pageSize: varPageSize`, you're assigning the immutable value of varPageSize at the time of execution. You're not assigning a reference to varPageSize. So `pageSize` will not update when you change `varPageSize` (this is how JavaScript works, not Kendo UI specific).

In order to do what you want, you need to call `dataSource.pageSize(varPageSize)` after changing it, and then `grid.refresh()` to apply this change to the grid.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/yv44a/1/) for an example.

Comment: This solved it, thanks! I'm new to both JavaScript and jQuery, but I understand this now - especially after seeing why it doesn't work. I didn't have to call grid.refresh(), though. Adding it to the function call actually threw an error.